# How do I debug Roaming Profile synchronisation (or lack thereof) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, roaming-profile

We're running a Server 2008-based domain with Windows 7 clients. Recently a desktop of ours persistently started giving its user a TEMP profile on login. We assumed a broken profile and did what we normally, which was to rename both the cached and server copies of the profile, in order to create a new one from scratch.

On the next login, the server created the new profile folder, but the user still was only given a temporary profile. All networking and domain connectivity on the PC is working fine, the user is active and is able to use Exchange and access file shares with no trouble. No other users in the same OU and security groups have had any problems. There are no delays or timeouts to speak of and the desktop appears clean and healthy.

I've found plenty of guides for debugging roaming profiles, but they only work up to the point of Server 2003/XP (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833). Microsoft seem to have specifically disabled this functionality in Vista/7.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a guide to enabling this? At the moment, just having the option of staring blankly at reams of impenetrable gibberish would be a step forward...

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, you might even try deleting the key that corresponds to the user's logon.

Comment: Fantastic, that sorted my original problem. After deleting the SIDs for the relevant users it was able to create a fresh, stable profile. Thank you!